# Seville to Cadiz by train in May - should we buy tickets in advance?

Tags: trains, bookings, seville

We (2 people) will be taking a train from Seville to Cadiz in May. It will be a Tuesday at about 10.00am. Would there be any need to buy tickets in advance or will we be okay to buy tickets when we get to the station an hour before departure?

Comment: I have not bothered all the times (about 10) I have done that journey. It is a relatively local journey, and we always got seats.

Comment: It might be worth checking if there are any local holidays or major events taking place that day in case that affects availability. And I guess the advisability of booking ahead might depend on how important getting a seat on that particular train is to your travel plans.

Comment: @Traveller That's a good suggestion about checking holidays.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your actual experience with this route sounds like an Answer.